# Not able to plot histogram in R Shiny due to the presence of NA's in data

Tags: r, shiny, histogram

I am creating a Shiny app where in there is drop down which sends the value to the server for histogram to be created.

Code is shown below

UI :

```
 selectInput(inputId = "diamonds", 
              label = "choose a category in Diamonds", 
              choices = c("Length", "Breath", "Height"," Please Select a Type "),
              selected = " Please Select a Type " ),
```

Server :

```
datasetInput <- reactive({ 
    switch(input$dataset, 
           "Length" = diamonds$x, 
           "Breath" = diamonds$y, 
           "Height" = diamonds$z,
           " Please Select a Type " = NULL) 
  }) 
  output$hist <- eventReactive(input$action,{hist(rnorm(input$diamonds))
  })
```

So when I select anything from my drop down and click submit button it displays

```
Error Msg: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6691 Warning in rnorm(input$diamonds) : NAs introduced by coercion Warning: Error in rnorm: invalid arguments Stack trace (innermost first):   
    100: rnorm
     99: hist
     98: eventReactiveHandler [#10]
     78: output$hist
      4: <Anonymous>
      3: do.call
      2: print.shiny.appobj
      1: <Promise>
```

How to avoid NA's while creating a histogram?

Comment: you should provide ui and server complete, so that we can reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the actual problem was with the rnorm() method. Here, if we are using rnorm() it is giving same result irrepective of any selection in the switch case. To get the exact Histogram we have to remove rnorm method and then call datasetInput() method.

```
datasetInput <- reactive({ 
    switch(input$diamonds1, 
           "Length" = diamonds$x, 
           "Breath" = diamonds$y, 
           "Height" = diamonds$z,
           " Please Select a Type " = NULL) 
  }) 
  output$hist <- eventReactive(input$action,{**hist(datasetInput())**
```

Thanks for your help @divibisan you got me close to thesolution.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with the `NA`s. Read the second part of that error message: `Error in rnorm: invalid arguments Stack trace (innermost first)`

The problem is that `rnorm()` accepts a numeric argument that determines how many random numbers to produce from a normal distribution. You call it with `rnorm(input$diamonds)`, where `input$diamonds` returns the selected value of your `selectInput`, all of which are character strings: `choices = c("Length", "Breath", "Height"," Please Select a Type ")`

Your code should be:

```
datasetInput <- reactive({ 
    switch(input$diamonds, 
           "Length" = diamonds$x, 
           "Breath" = diamonds$y, 
           "Height" = diamonds$z,
           " Please Select a Type " = NULL) 
  })
  output$hist <- eventReactive(input$action,{hist(rnorm(datasetInput()))
  })
```

You need to call `datasetInput()` in your `rnorm()` call so you get the appropriate numeric values, not `input$diamonds` which returns the selection as a character